# django urlresolver throwing error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

I have created a Django project `foo`.

```
├── manage.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── templates
    │   ├── xyz.html
    │   └── abc.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

In `views.py` , I have created two class based view `HomePage` and `ListPage`
And routing configuration defined like this in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view() , name='home'),
    url(r'^list$', ListPage.as_view(), name='list'),
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Throws Error:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
>>> resolve('/')
ResolverMatch(func=<function HomePage at 0x7f77769bb9d8>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='home', app_name='None', namespace='')
>>> resolve('list')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
...
raise Resolver404({'path': path})
django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404: {'path': 'list'}
```

What's going wrong here? Default root url '/' is resolving but 'list' is not resolving

Comment: Have you tried resolve("/list")

Comment: it was a noob mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This was a silly mistake of mine :). Though It might be helpful to somebody.

try

```
>>resolve('/list')
```